# Using as.factor to create a new categorical value in r

Tags: r, statistics, categorical-data

I am not that good at coding in r and I need help for a stats class project. I need to create a new categorical value `degOB` in r that relates back to a value `POBAD` from my database `dd`.

degOB = 0 for POBAD <= 30 , 1 for 30 < POBAD <= 33,  2 for 33 < POBAD
I must use 'as.factor' to do so but I am not sure how to set this up

Comment: `?cut` is the best option to use in this case

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to do this is with `cut` as @Jaap mentioned. First we need to create some data the is similar to yours:

```
set.seed(42)
POBAD <- sample(25:40, 25, replace=TRUE)
dd <- data.frame(POBAD)
```

Now we add the new variable:

```
dd$degOB <- cut(dd$POBAD, breaks=c(0, 30, 33, max(dd$POBAD)))
levels(dd$degOB) <- 0:2
str(dd)
# 'data.frame': 25 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ POBAD: int  25 29 25 33 34 28 26 34 25 40 ...
#  $ degOB: Factor w/ 3 levels "0","1","2": 1 1 1 2 3 1 1 3 1 3 ...
```

That is the easy way to do it. Using `as.factor` just makes it more complicated, but if you want to do that, use this statement instead of the one using `cut`.

```
dd$degOB <- as.factor(ifelse(dd$POBAD <= 30, 0, ifelse(dd$POBAD > 30 & dd$POBAD <= 33, 1, 2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

To help you, please post your code and what you have tried so far, rather than looking like us doing your homework for you :)

Setup a factor function and feed it the vectors like [here](https://www.guru99.com/r-factor-categorical-continuous.html)

```
# Create Ordinal categorical vector 
degree_vector <- c('degOB', 'POBAD', ...)
# Convert `degree_vector` to a factor with ordered level
factor_degree <- factor(degree_vector, order = TRUE, levels =c('degOB', 'POBAD', '', ))
# Print the new variable
factor_degree
```

---

**Option 2**: Much *simpler* to understand, this is what I do

```
# Step 1 setup your data frame
d <- data.frame(variable = c("degOB", "POBAD", "", ""))

# Step 2 your factor
d$variable.r <- as.integer(as.factor(d$variable))

# Step 3 add a mapping to your degrees fill out the rest
mapping <- c("degOB" = 0, "POBAD"  <= 30, ...)
d$variable.r <- mapping[d$variable]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I tried:
dd$degOB = as.factor(ifelse(dd$POBAD<=30, 0, ifelse(30 < dd$POBAD & dd$POBAD <= 33, 1, ifelse(dd$POBAD > 33, 2, NA))))

and I believe I got the correct answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The database is already established with other variables and was obtained by getcsv = function(x) read.csv(file=paste("http://www.umich.edu/~dnoll/BME503/",x,sep=""), header=T)
dd = getcsv("diabetes_dat.csv")
attach(dd)